# Mysql server not connecting anymore with servername

Tags: php, mysql

I was connected with my server using my server name.

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');

$servername = "my server name here";
$username = "xxxxx";
$pass = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";


$conn = mysqli_connect ($servername, $username, $pass, $dbname);
if(!$conn) {
die("Connection faild: ".mysqli_connect_error());   
}

$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");


?>
```

All my aplications was working and now stopped.
Now is only connecting if i use my server ip.

There are the errors
**Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Connection faild: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

**

When i connect on the database with my login and pssword in my host provider
it enters fine,nothing changed.

Btw im using xampp.

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: `php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed` -- it can no longer resolve the address you were using. If it's a custom address, make sure it's in your hosts file. If it's an actual registered address, it could be a DNS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, using xampp in Windows, we will set server name be "localhost"

```
$servername = "localhost";
```

If you want other name, please set in hosts file:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 my_domain_name.com
```

And add "my_domain_name.com" (for example) into $servername variable

Comment: $servername = "my server name here";

I do not know correct value you set for $servername
If not "localhost", or not set in hosts file, it will be wrong.

and no space in server name. for example: "my server name"

Answer (score 1):

Use that

```
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "project2");


// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```